# Woocommerce - add field to Check pay method

Tags: woocommerce, payment

I'd like to add a field on Check Payment that allows the order processor to insert a check number...please help!  Check payment orders will only be entered by staff, not the public.
[Add Field Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvnVb.png)

I've searched all over and I'm stumped.

Comment: I have added a bunch of code here with visualized images. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have also added the condition where only admin user can see check number field not any public user.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, I have created this snippet which will help you with your requirement.

```
// add a field on the check payment type
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_description', 'custom_check_payment_field', 10, 2 );
function custom_check_payment_field( $description, $payment_id ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user  = wp_get_current_user();
        $current_user_role = (array) $user->roles;

        if ( 'cheque' === $payment_id && $current_user_role[0] == 'administrator') {
            ob_start();

            echo '<div  class="cheque-field">';
            woocommerce_form_field(
                'customer_cheque_number',
                array(
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'label'    => __( 'Enter cheque number', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'class'    => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
                    'required' => true,
                ),
                ''
            );
            echo '<div>';

            $description .= ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
    return $description;
}
```

```
// save check number in meta/database
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_customer_cheque_number_order_meta', 10, 2 );
function save_customer_cheque_number_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['customer_cheque_number'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['customer_cheque_number'] ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_customer_cheque_number', esc_attr( $_POST['customer_cheque_number'] ) );
    }
}
```

```
// show check number on orders page (OPTONAL)
add_action( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'display_customer_cheque_number_on_order_totals', 10, 3 );
function display_customer_cheque_number_on_order_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    if ( $order->get_payment_method() === 'cheque' && $customer_cheque_number = $order->get_meta( '_customer_cheque_number' ) ) {
        $sorted_total_rows = array();

        foreach ( $total_rows as $key_row => $total_row ) {
            $sorted_total_rows[ $key_row ] = $total_row;
            if ( $key_row === 'payment_method' ) {
                $sorted_total_rows['customer_cheque_number'] = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Cheque number', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'value' => esc_html( $customer_cheque_number ),
                );
            }
        }
        $total_rows = $sorted_total_rows;
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
```

[image]

```
// add meta box on orders on woocommerce backend
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxes_callback' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'add_meta_boxes_callback' ) ) {
    function add_meta_boxes_callback() {
        add_meta_box( 'shop_order_fields', __( 'Cheque number', 'woocommerce' ), 'orders_cheque_number_custom_meta', 'shop_order', 'side', 'core' );
    }
}

// show meta field with entered check number
if ( ! function_exists( 'orders_cheque_number_custom_meta' ) ) {
    function orders_cheque_number_custom_meta() {
        global $post;

        $check_number = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customer_cheque_number', true ) ? get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customer_cheque_number', true ) : '';
        ?>
        <input type="text" style="width:250px;margin-top:15px" readonly name="readonly_check_number" value="<?php echo $check_number; ?>"></p>
        <?php
    }
}
```

[image]